# Do you have or have you?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

I am a English learner and I still don't understand why the auxiliary verb **"to do"** doesn't appear with the verb **"to have"**.

Is it wrong to say

> "She doesn't have brown hair"?

Comment: "She doesn't have brown hair" is correct and common. *Do* often appears with *have*.  Can you try to explain exactly what you've been told about *do* and *have*?

Comment: The verb is have, the auxiliary for the verb have for a question and a negative is do or does. This is very basic.

Comment: It's very basic, but it's not true for British English. The use of an auxiliary with _have_ is optional in British English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auxiliary "do" doesn't appear with the **auxiliary** "have".  Not every "have" acts as an auxiliary.

> She doesn't have brown hair.

This sentence is fine.  This "have" is the main verb of its clause.

> *She doesn't have bleached her hair.
>     She hasn't bleached her hair.

Here, he main verb is the particple "bleached".  The "has" is an auxiliary.  The auxiliary "do" doesn't belong in this sentence.  On the other hand:

> She doesn't have bleached hair.

In this example, the participle "bleached" directly modifies "hair", much like the adjective "brown" does in my first example.  The main verb of the clause is still "have", and the auxiliary "doesn't" is the natural way to negate this sentence.

> Baa baa, black sheep
>   Have you any wool?

This is from an old nursery rhyme.  It's still perfectly good English, although it sounds a bit old-fashioned to my contemporary American ear.

> Do you have any wool?

This version would break the rhythm of the original poem, but it's the version that my American dialect finds more natural.

There are at least two situations here, and they depend on dialect.  One situation has to do with *do-support* for negation -- whether "doesn't have" or "hasn't" is appropriate.  Another situation has to do with *do-support* for forming questions -- whether "do you have" or "have you" is appropriate.  A possible third situation is whether *do-support* for emphases is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When I was young, say fifty years ago, using *do* support with *have* was American: in British English we simply didn't say *Do you have* (unless we meant in a habitual sense): we said *Have you got*, or (in a more formal register) *Have you*.

Since then, *Do you have* and *I don't have* have become more common in British English, but they haven't completely driven out the other forms.

(When *have* is an auxiliary, nobody uses *do* with it: *Have you seen it?*, not *Do you have seen it?*